# Wrong number of type parameters for overload function createDirectStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am new to spark scala and while trying to run this simple code which tries to read from a kafka topic, I am bogged down by an error while creating direct stream suggest I am providing wrong number of type parameters for overload function createDirectStream. Below is the line where I am getting error

```
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream [String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder]
(streamingContext, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
```

And below is the full code.

```
package com.test.spark

import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.spark
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder

import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._

import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object KafkaAirDRsProcess {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("AirDR Kafka to Spark")

    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))

    // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
    val brokers = "10.21.165.145:6667 "
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> brokers)

    val topics="AIRMAIN , dummy"
    val topicsSet = topics.split(",").toSet
    //val topicsSet=topics.map(_.toString).toSet

    val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream [String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder]
    (streamingContext, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
    val LinesDStream = messages.map(_._2)
    val AirDRStream= LinesDStream.map(AirDRFilter.parseAirDR)

    AirDRStream.foreachRDD(foreachFunc = rdd => {
      System.out.println("--- New RDD with " + rdd.count() + " records");

      if (rdd.count() > 0) {
        rdd.toDF().registerTempTable("AirDRTemp")
        val FilteredCDR = sqlContext.sql("select * from AirDRTemp"  )

        println("======================print result =================")
        FilteredCDR.show()
      }

    });

    //streamingContext.checkpoint("/tmp/mytest/ckpt/")
    streamingContext.start()
    streamingContext.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Below is the snapshot of intellij error

[image]

Comment: You need to post the error as well.

Comment: As you may see from the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka010/KafkaUtils.scala), `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream` takes only two generic type params `[K, V]`, but the code of the question contains four of them. Have you tried with `[String, StringDecoder]` only?

Comment: Yes I did. But still did not work. Actually I got this sample code from spark examples and they did same. Not sure what is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using kafka-0-10 you can create InputDStream as below

```
    import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe



  val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
    "bootstrap.servers" -> "10.21.165.145:6667:9092",
    "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
    "enable.auto.commit" -> (true: java.lang.Boolean)
  )

  val topics = ???

  val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
    streamingContext,
    PreferConsistent,
    Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
  )
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am still getting same error Shankar. It did not work. I am using IntelliJ and it keeps highlighting createDirectStream as red mentioning wrong number of parameters.

Comment: @omer can you share the screenshot of error ? and did you changed what I suggested ?

Comment: What version of spark and are you using ?

Comment: I have added the snapshot.

Comment: I am using spark 2.1.1 with scala 2.11.8 and kafka 0.10 .

Comment: I manually added  spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.1.1.jar to intelliJ which does contain KafkaUtils but this error is suggesting I am doing it wrong though this is the same code available in spark examples.

Comment: If you are using kafka-0-10 then you can follow example from here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html

Comment: Thanks Shankar. Yes this works with Kafka 0.10. Too much difference between different versions. sigh

Comment: Ok, yeah there is a difference and at first I didnot notice that you were using kafka 10.